# Why does my matrix print in 3 rows and multiple columns while i need the opposite? How can i also decrypt the message?

Tags: c++, testing, encryption

******I am trying to encrypt a message by having it print in 3 columns and as many rows as needed. I also need help with reversing my encryption***

I am having most difficulties printing my results. I am working with a  Rail Fence Cipher key N which dictate number of columns. N = Number of Columns, but in my code I made it default = 3.
My Conditions are
.The plaintext is written, the sequence of each letter’s vertical position on the columns varies right and left in a repeating cycle
.The ciphertext is then read off in columns***

```
  int main()
    {
        int num_cols, num_spaces=0 ,f=0;
        
        string message;
        
        // accept the message from the user
        cout<<" Enter the message to encrypt : ";
        getline(cin,message);
        num_cols=3;
        
        // first we need to remove any spaces that might be there in the message
        for(int i = 0 ; i<message.size(); ++i)
        {
            if(message[i] == ' ')
            {
                ++num_spaces;
            }
        }
        remove(message.begin(), message.end(),' ');
        message.resize(message.size() - num_spaces);
    
        
        cout<<"\n The equivalent cipher text would be : "<<endl;
        vector<vector<char>> matrix(3,vector<char>(message.size(),' '));
        
        // encrypt the message
        for(int i=0,j=0; i<message.size(); i++)
            {
            matrix[j][i] = message[i];
            if(j == 3-1)
                    {
                f=1;
            }
            else if(j==0)
                f=0;
            if(f==0)
                    {
                j++;
            }
            else j--;
        }
        
        // Printing the grid
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < message.size(); j++) 
            {
                cout << matrix[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    
        return 0;
        // end

}
```

Comment: Well, "printing the grid" loop makes three iterations, and therefore calls `cout << endl` exactly three times. That's why the output consists of three rows. Perhaps you meant to switch the two nested loops around.

Comment: i tried it and all hat does is print the message as is, not encrypted. Also doesn't print in a matrix

Comment: Show the code that you tried. I, for one, can't help with code I can't see.

Comment: This is the original display code, but even after reverting it , it still didn't work as required . for(int i=0;i<num_cols;i++)
  {
   cout<<endl;
        for(int j=0;j<message.size();j++)
                {
                // omit spaces while displaying the cipher text
                if(matrix[i][j] != ' ')
                cout<<matrix[i][j];
        }
   cout<<endl;
    }

Comment: This code still calls `cout<<endl;` three times; moving that call to a different place in the other loop doesn't change that, as long as that outer loop loops three times. You want the outer loop to loop over `j`, and the inner loop over `i`. So that you print `size` rows of three characters each, not three rows of `size` characters each.

Comment: If you mean like this [   for(int j=0;j<num_cols;j++)
  {
   cout<<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<message.size();i++)
                {
                // omit spaces while displaying the cipher text
                if(matrix[i][j] != ' ')
                cout<<matrix[i][j];
        }
   cout<<endl;
    }
 ]

Comment: That doesnt work , there is not dispaly, even if i did remove the endl

Comment: The other loop should make `message.size()` iterations, the inner loop should make 3 iterations. You keep doing it the wrong way round.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235756/discussion-between-unison-coding-and-igor-tandetnik).

Answer (score 0):

So, your first problem, the correct output is easy to solve. You had just a minor typo. The encrypted text will be printed with:

```
    // Printing the grid
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].size(); j++)
        {
            if (matrix[i][j] != ' ')
                std::cout << matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
```

If you want to see the rails, then please use:

```
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].size(); j++)
        {
                std::cout << matrix[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
```

So, with that the question is answered.

Deciphering is similar simple.

You create again rails and do for the length of the string the same as before. But, do not put a letter in that position, but a marker, for example a '*'.

Then go rail by rail (row by row) through your rails, and everytime, when you find a marker, the replace that marker with the next character from the encrypted text.

Then go again zigzag through your rails, and collect all characters at the corresponding positions. The result will be the drcrypted text.

I prepared a complete solution for encryption and decryption. The number of rails can be specified at the top. In my example I use 5. Please change it to 3, if you want. I made it straigthforward. For easier understanding. The code should be further optimized. E.g., there are a lot of repetions that could be put into functions.

Anyway. It is just an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// Please specify the number of rails:
constexpr size_t NumberOfRails = 5u;

constexpr char EmptyRailPosition = '.';
constexpr char UsedRailPosition = '*';

// Some aliases for easier writing and understanding
using Rail = std::vector<char>;
using Rails = std::vector<Rail>;

std::string clearText{ "abcd efgh ijkl mnopqrst uv wxyz" };

int main() {

    // Remove all spaces from string
    clearText.erase(std::remove_if(clearText.begin(), clearText.end(), ::isspace), clearText.end());

    // Create the rails for the encryption
    Rails encryptedRails(NumberOfRails, Rail(clearText.length(), EmptyRailPosition));

    // Now encrypt
    int railIndexIncrementor{ -1 };
    size_t railIndex{};

    // Go thorugh all characters in the clear string
    for (size_t columnIndexInClearText{}; columnIndexInClearText < clearText.length(); ++columnIndexInClearText) {

        // Write character on rail
        encryptedRails[railIndex][columnIndexInClearText] = clearText[columnIndexInClearText];

        // If we are at the top or at the bottom of our rails, then change direction
        if (0 == (columnIndexInClearText % (NumberOfRails-1))) 
            railIndexIncrementor = -railIndexIncrementor;
        
        // Modify rail index. Increment or decrement. Depending on railIncrementor
        railIndex = static_cast<int>(railIndex) + railIndexIncrementor;
    }

    
    // Here we will store the encrypted message
    std::string encryptedMessage{};

    // Show rails
    std::cout << "\nRails: \n\n";
    for (const Rail& rail : encryptedRails) {
        for (const char c : rail) {
            std::cout << c;
            // Build string with encrypted message
            if (c != EmptyRailPosition) encryptedMessage += c;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    // Show encrypted message
    std::cout << "\n\nEncrypted message: \n\n" << encryptedMessage << "\n\n";


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    // Decryption
    
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Build empty rails
    Rails decryptedRails(NumberOfRails, Rail(clearText.length(), '.'));

    railIndexIncrementor = -1;
    railIndex = 0;

    // Go through all necessary positions in the decryption rails
    for (size_t columnIndexInEncryptedText{}; columnIndexInEncryptedText < encryptedMessage.length(); ++columnIndexInEncryptedText) {

        // Write makrker on rail
        decryptedRails[railIndex][columnIndexInEncryptedText] = UsedRailPosition;

        // If we are at the top or at the bottom of our rails, then change direction
        if (0 == (columnIndexInEncryptedText % (NumberOfRails - 1)))
            railIndexIncrementor = -railIndexIncrementor;

        // Modify rail index. Increment or decrement. Depending on railIncrementor
        railIndex = static_cast<int>(railIndex) + railIndexIncrementor;
    }

    // Show rails with markers
    std::cout << "\n\nRails with markers: \n\n";
    for (const Rail& rail : decryptedRails) {
        for (const char c : rail)  std::cout << c;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    // Now exchange the markers with the characters of the encrypted string
    size_t indexInEncryptedMessage{};

    // Now, put a character from the string at positions with marker
    for (Rail& rail : decryptedRails)
        for (char& c : rail)
            if (c == UsedRailPosition) c = encryptedMessage[indexInEncryptedMessage++];

    // Show rails with replaced markers
    std::cout << "\nRails with replaced markers, so decrypted rails:\n\n";
    for (const Rail& rail : encryptedRails) {
        for (const char c : rail)  std::cout << c;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }


    // Read back string from rails
    railIndexIncrementor = -1;
    railIndex = 0;
    std::string decrytpedMessage{};

    // Go through all necessary positions in the decryption rails
    for (size_t columnIndexInEncryptedText{}; columnIndexInEncryptedText < encryptedMessage.length(); ++columnIndexInEncryptedText) {

        // Read character from rail
        decrytpedMessage += decryptedRails[railIndex][columnIndexInEncryptedText];

        // If we are at the top or at the bottom of our rails, then change direction
        if (0 == (columnIndexInEncryptedText % (NumberOfRails - 1)))
            railIndexIncrementor = -railIndexIncrementor;

        // Modify rail index. Increment or decrement. Depending on railIncrementor
        railIndex = static_cast<int>(railIndex) + railIndexIncrementor;
    }

    // and, show decrypted message
    std::cout << "\n\nDecypted message:\n\n" << decrytpedMessage << "\n\n";


    return 0;
}
```